# C sharp JSON serialization when DataMember is not always an array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization

I am receiving JSON data from a web service.  This is an api for a stock trading website where quotes can be requested.  Multiple quotes can be requested; when multiple quotes are requested, the data comes back as array, ie:

```
"quote":[
    {quote1},{quote2},...{quoten}
]
```

However, when only a single quote is requested, instead of returning an array with a single element, it returns it as a value, ie:

```
"quote":{singlequote}
```

instead of

```
"quote":[
    {singlequote}
]
```

For this value, my class includes:

```
[DataContract]
public class QuoteWrapper
{
    [DataMember(Name = "quote", IsRequired = true)]
    public Quote[] Quotes { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine whenever I request multiple quotes and it comes back as an array.  However when I request a single quote it fails for it not being an array.  Is there anything that can be done about this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you intercept the JSON and use Regex to look for the `"quote":{singlequote}` condition? Then you could modify it to the `"quote":[ {singlequote} ]` form before handing it to to your deserialization.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm working on as I type this.  Seems to me to be the path of least resistance